# How to insert images in MongoDB with their "_id "number, with name in images and the details?

Tags: python, mongodb

how to create collections just like creating table in SQL using Python in MongoDB
and I should insert the images with the names that is on the Given in the file name path .I should break the image name as 3 collections
1)serial number
2)roll number
3)timestamps
with the below code I have inserted One photo into the MongoDB but I need to insert many images with above collections at a time
import pymongo
import gridfs
import base64
if **name** == '**main**':

```
# read in the image.
filename = "D:/testing/inserting/1654110510_10_34985100_00005.jpg"
datafile = open(filename,"rb");
thedata = datafile.read()
b64 = base64.b64encode(thedata)

# connect to database 
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017);
database = connection['images']
# create a new gridfs object.
fs = gridfs.GridFS(database)

# store the data in the database Returns the id of the file in gridFS 
stored = fs.put(b64, filename="1654110510")
# retrieve what was just stored. 
outputdata =fs.get(stored).read()

# create an output file and store the image in the output file
decode_b64 = base64.b64decode(b64)
outfilename = "D:/testing/1654110510.jpg" 
output= open(outfilename,"wb")

output.write(decode_b64)
```

Comment: I don't think your question is clear. Please [edit] your question and try to state more clearly what your desired outcome is and what your problem is. In addition, your code still contains an indentation error that would prevent it from running.

Comment: sorry about that this is first time I have raised the request that but now I changed the questions for more understanding